# How to get static (snapshot of) pw-top?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, pipewire

I need to get a static output from pw-top, of pipewire, for a script I want to make. I really just need a list of pipewire devices.

For example, I want to be able to run `pw-top | grep output` and then do stuff to that. Basically, I want to get a list pf pipewire devices and their IDs.

Sort of output I want, for speakers and headphones only:

```
<device name> <id>
<device name> <id>
<device name> <id>
```

etc

I tried the following:

```
[aggam@aggam-archlinux ~]$ pactl list cards | grep -E 'port.type|Name|Card'
Card #39
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.type = "hdmi"
Card #40
    Name: alsa_card.usb-0c76_USB_PnP_Audio_Device-00
                port.type = "mic"
Card #41
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3
                port.type = "mic"
                port.type = "mic"
                port.type = "line"
                port.type = "line"
                port.type = "headphones"
                port.type = "spdif"
```

But

1. some show up as speakers and mics? I assume the headphones are both...
2. those are pulseaudio devices, and I want to avoid issues, so I want their pipewire device ID

EDIT 2:
my pw-top:

```
S   ID  QUANT   RATE    WAIT    BUSY   W/Q   B/Q  ERR FORMAT           NAME
S   28      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  Dummy-Driver
S   29      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  Freewheel-Driver
S   36      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  Midi-Bridge
S   42      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra3
S   43      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  alsa_input.usb-0c76_USB_PnP_Audio_Device-00.mono-fallback
S   44      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
S   45      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
S   71      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  alsa_output.usb-KURZWEIL_MPS-Piano-00.analog-stereo
S   69      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  alsa_input.usb-KURZWEIL_MPS-Piano-00.analog-stereo
I   67      0      0   0.0us   0.0us  0.00  0.00    0    F32LE 2 48000 Firefox
```

notice how the piano output is 71.
output of `pactl list short sinks` is

```
42  alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra3 PipeWire    s32le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
44  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo  PipeWire    s32le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
401 alsa_output.usb-KURZWEIL_MPS-Piano-00.analog-stereo PipeWire    s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

notice how the piano is 401 all of a sudden...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us exactly what information you want to extract. Since `pw-top` is designed to be used as a live monitor, it is almost certainly not the best way for you to get whatever info you need in a script. If you explain what you need, we should be able to give you another way to get it.

Comment: @terdon I want to get a list pf pipewire devices and their IDs

Comment: `pactl list cards`

Comment: Yes, please ***EDIT*** your question and tell us what you need there because comments are easy to miss, hard to read and can be deleted without warning. Also, we need to see exactly what you need. What is the output of `pw-top` that you would like to have? We need to know exactly what you need to be able to give you a good alternative.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov yeah but I want to get speakers/headphones, and it's gonna be annoying to format. pw-top's format is really convenient... is there an alternative?

Comment: If you show us what you need, we will show you how to get it, but we cannot help you if you don't show what format you actually want to have. Show us what you would like to get from `pw-top | grep output` and how you would like to use it and we can help you get it. But you won't be able to use pw-top since it is not designed to be parseable.

Comment: @terdon I want a list of output devices, with their names and IDs, so I can switch to them. I want to make a dmenu for switching audio devices.

Comment: So you just need something like this: `pactl list cards | awk '(/^Card/){sub(/#/,"",$2); id=$2} ($1~/^Name:/){print id,$2}`? Ah, just saw your edit, that's perfect thank you! Someone more knowledgeable than I am should be able to help now!

Comment: or just `pactl list short cards`? or `pactl list short sinks`?

Comment: @terdon `pactl list short sinks` is the closest one to what I'm looking for, since it actually has pipewire ID's (same ones that show up on pw-top), but for one of my devices the ID is different for some reason...

Comment: Great, one step closer then! OK, please add the output you get to your question and show the output you would want (preferably by showing what you see in `pw-top` so we can compare). Also have a look at `man pactl` in case that helps.

Comment: @terdon I made an edit. also, thank you so much for your help and patience!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
I ended up not using a shell command, rather I made an entire python script.
The script gets all devices, makes a dictionary of them and then lets you use dmenu/bemenu to select which one you want.

the script can be found here [on my github](https://github.com/AggamR/shell-scripts/blob/main/menu_pw_devices.py), but the code for just that part is:

```py
sp = subprocess.run(['wpctl', 'status'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')\
        .split("Sinks")[1].split('├─')[0]
newsp = []

for line in sp.split('\n'):
    if '.' in line:
        newsp.append(line.replace(' ', '')[1:])

devices = {}  # name: id
for line in newsp:
    line = line.split('.')
    devices[line[1].split('[vol')[0]] = line[0].replace('*', '')
```